# Axios bad request 400 Spotify post

Tags: axios, spotify, http-status-code-400

I am getting a bad request of 400 from Axios for trying to get the token from the Spotify API. Can someone please look at my code?. I would really appreciate someone's help.

```
app.get("/auth/callback", async (req, res) => {
try{
    let code = req.query.code || null;
    let state = req.query.state || null;
    let data = qs.stringify({
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
    });
    const response = await axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', data,
    {
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    })
    res.send(response)
  }catch(error){
    res.send(error)
}
```

})

Comment: 400, usually indicates there is something wrong with your payload. Usually, the error will come with a message describing what is wrong. If you share the error log, we should be able to help you more.

Comment: Hi @Renato thank you for your help. This is the error I am getting.  `"message":"Request failed with status code 400","name":"AxiosError","config":{"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"env":{},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: I found the solution to why it was giving an error. I needed to add the code_verifier in the stringify to return the  acces_token.